# member function pointer using dlib was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, optimization, dlib, pointer-to-member

I'm searching to optimize an error of approximation using the dlib library...
so let's say I have Point (x,y) and a vector of values, which are used to find the minimum and fit the error locally, so I implemented this class:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <dlib/optimization.h>
class Point
{
   int _x, _y;
public:
    Point(int x, int y): _x(x), _y(y){}

    double findError(const double& psi)
    {
        auto err = std::erf(_x - psi) - std::erf(_y-psi);
        return std::pow(err,2);
    }
    double optimize(const Point& p, dlib::matrix<double,0,1> &psiValues)
    {
         auto err = p->*findError ;
         dlib::find_min_box_constrained(bfgs_search_strategy(),  
                             objective_delta_stop_strategy(1e-9),  
                             findError, derivative(findError), psiValues, {0.1,0.5,0.9},{0.1,0.4,0.8 });
        return psiValues(0);
    }
};
```

and this code don't compile so I tried to extract the optimizer in a static class    like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
//#include <dlib/optimization.h>
class Point
{
   int _x, _y;
public:
   Point(int x, int y): _x(x), _y(y){}

    double findError(const double& psi)
   {
       auto err = std::erf(_x - psi) - std::erf(_y-psi);
       return std::pow(err,2);
   }
};

class Errorcalculator
{
public:

    static double optimize(const Point& p, std::vector<double> &psiValues)
    {
        auto err = p->*findError ;
        // dlib::find_min_box_constrained(bfgs_search_strategy(),  
        //                     objective_delta_stop_strategy(1e-9),  
        //                     p->*findError, derivative(p->*findError), psiValue, {0.1,0.9 },{0.1 0.8});
        return 0.0;
    }
 };
```

now I'm getting (the same compile error using dlib function with or without static keyword)

> error: 'findError' was not declared in this scope

How is it possible if the point p is declared as parameter? How can I use the dlib function wrapped in the class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

findError is member method, but isn't pointer.
For creating pointer to method use next syntax:
*return value* (*class_name*::* *pointer_name*)(*method arguments*);
Sample:

```
class widget
{
public:
    unsigned char foo(long long, double) {}
};
int main()
{
    // declaration of pointer
    unsigned char (widget::*ptr_to_method)(long long, double);
    // setting the pointer on certain method in class (not object!)
    ptr_to_method = &widget::foo;
    // we have some object of widget class
    widget obj{};
    // using the pointer
    unsigned char res = (obj.*ptr_to_method)(10L, 10.0); // arguments
    // if we have obj as widget*, we'll use ->* syntax to call method
}
```

In this sample we used local pointer, may be you would to use global pointer.
Read more, for example, [here](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members)

Answer (score 1):

based on the answer of [acade](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10025445/acade), the issue of comiling is solved. But I add here my solution as an answer to solve the use of Dlib library

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <vector>
 #include <cmath>
 #include <dlib/optimization.h>
 class Point
 {
    int _x, _y;
 public:
    Point(int x, int y): _x(x), _y(y){}

    double findError(const double& psi)
    {
        auto err = std::erf(_x - psi) - std::erf(_y-psi);
        return std::pow(err,2);
    }
    double optimize(double &psiValue, dlib::matrix<double,0,1>& lowerValues, dlib::matrix<double,0,1>& upperValues)
    {
        auto lambdaError = [this](const double& param) -> double
         { return this->findError(param);};

        auto lambdaDerivativeError = [this](const double& param) -> double 
         {return dlib::derivative(lambdaError)(param);};

        dlib::find_min_box_constrained(bfgs_search_strategy(),  
                         objective_delta_stop_strategy(1e-9),
                         lambdaError, lambdaDerivativeError, 
                         psiValue, lowerValues, upperValues);
        return psiValue;
    }


 };
```

the idea is to use parametrized Lambda functions that encapsulate the member functions